# missing libgeos_c.so on OSX

Tags: django, macos, postgresql, postgis, homebrew

I am trying to install Postgis in order to use GeoDjango on OSX.

For this, I first uninstalled postgres completely, then I installed everything following the GeoDjango documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#homebrew

I did the following:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install postgresql
brew install postgis
brew install gdal
brew install libgeoip
```

When I run my Django project, I get the following error:

```
OSError at / dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so, 6): image not found
```

I ran

```
sudo find . -name "libgeos_c*"
```

And got:

```
./Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
./Users/martin/opt/geos-3.3.0/capi/.deps/libgeos_c_la-geos_c.Plo
./Users/martin/opt/geos-3.3.0/capi/.deps/libgeos_c_la-geos_ts_c.Plo
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.3/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.3/lib/libgeos_c.a
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.3/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.4/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.4/lib/libgeos_c.a
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.4/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.5/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.5/lib/libgeos_c.a
./usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.3.5/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
./usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib
./usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.a
./usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
```

As you can see, no ".so" files at all. Any suggestions?

*Edit:*

Out of desperation I also installed the KyngChaos Packages and added the following settings:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/GEOS' 
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/GDAL' 
GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/geoip/1.4.8/lib/libGeoIP.dylib'
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: I did brew install geos on Mac. But the GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH is not the same on my machine as yours. Do you know, where it can be found? I tried to use find, but I couldn't find the .so file in any of the folders, which I have read permission to. I do not have sudo rights.

Comment: You should use the libgeos_c.dylib instead of  libgeos_c.so

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorry, that KyngChaos solution completely defeats the purpose of using homebrew.

The answer for homebrew users (at least, for this one) is to **uninstall `geos` and its dependencies** and **then reinstall `geos` and then its dependencies**.

This worked for me:

```
brew uninstall geos gdal geoip libspatialite librasterlite spatialite-gui spatialite-tools
brew cleanup
brew install geos
brew install gdal geoip libspatialite librasterlite spatialite-gui spatialite-tools
brew cleanup
```

It seems some `geos` dependencies are getting out of sync.

You can *verify the libraries that need to be installed* by tracking what this returns:

```
python -c 'import _ctypes; _ctypes.dlopen("/usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib")'
```

You'll see something like

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: [some geos dependent library].dylib requires version X.X.X or later, but libgeos_c.1.8.0.dylib provides version X.X.X.

brew uninstall [some geos dependency]
brew install [some geos dependency]
brew cleanup
```

Then rerun the above `python` command and either the problem will be resolved or it'll reveal another dependency to uninstall/install.

Comment: I think i'm close, now getting django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory, that python import test throws no errors.  I had to uninstall postgis, brew uninstall postgis and then install it again using brew.

Comment: After spending hours, finally this saved me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it this way.

```
$ brew install postgresql
$ brew install postgis
$ brew install gdal
$ brew install libgeoip
```

then in Django settings set this:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib'
```

Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The [installation instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#homebrew) appears to hold the answer, which is to set the environment variable `$GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: This pointed me into the correct direction. I ignored this part of the docs because firstly it appears under the KyngChaos section (I was following the Homebrew section) and secondly it says: "If you are using a previous version of Django (like 1.0.2), then you will have to add the following in your settings" and I am using Django 1.4. Out of desperation I also tried the KyngChaos route and while it does not create the missing file, I could get it running with some additional settings.

Answer (score 0):

Same here - after installing everything as directed, I went back and added the KyngChaos libraries, then added the three export statements to my ~/.bash_profile as listed above. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was able to solve it by uninstalling GDAL from Homebrew and installing the GDAL Complete package from KyngChaos: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (Mac OSX) and solved it by creating a sym link from `where I found the lib folder` to `where python was looking for it in the error message`.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.10.3/lib/libgeos_c.dylib ~/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
```

None of the environment variables worked, nor reinstalling