# Basemap install on mac without fink (I tried everything I can google)

Tags: macos, fink

I am a Python Noob. (Using Mac OS 10.12 & Python 3.7)
I'm trying to use mpl_toolkits.basemap

to execute the code

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I googled the way to get matplotlib and successfully installed it.
However, while it's possible to run "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap" in terminal on mac,

it fails to be loaded if I run the command within IDLE.

Then, I googled to figure out the issue and got the hint that 
it could be resolved if I install Basemap properly.

To install Basemap, I think I need to go with "FINK".

However, Fink is only available up to 10.5 OS while mine is 10.12.
And FINK website says do not update OS before upgrading FINK. 
However, it's too late for me. 
Cause I updated my OS longtime ago and recently I started to learn Python Using Mac.

So I guess, if there is a way to install Basemap not using apt-get,
(the codes below is from "[Python basemap module impossible to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import)")

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.5.0
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
sudo pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

I think my issue could be cleared. 
Since I'm really really noob, I'm not sure this is the reason for my failing in "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap".

What I tried so far is

**1) `brew install basemap`**
with the error of

> Error: No available formula with the name "basemap" 
>   ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run: 
>   git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

**2) `pip install basemap`**
with the error of

> Requirement already satisfied

**3) `sudo pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip`**

with the error of

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/tmp/pip-install-lux494o4/pyproj/

4) `conda install basemap`
with the following message of

> ## All requested packages already installed.

5) `conda install -c conda-forge basemap`
with the following message

> Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing
>   transaction: done

Can anyone help to install basemap properly so that I could run

```
"from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap"
```

in my IDLe? 
My IDLE Sheel keeps saying

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

while my terminal doesn't have problem with running the code.

Appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

any luck? I spent the day battling this as well. I had the most success when I tried downloading an older version of basemap.

I was using python 2.7 and this worked okay `sudo -H pip2 install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.1.0.tar.gz`

For python 3 try replacing `pip2` with `pip3` or `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself today my solution:

1. install libgeos on mac

`brew install geos`

2. then as you suggested use pip to install mpl_tools:

`pip3 install -q https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip`

This also may help:
[missing libgeos_c.so on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294556/missing-libgeos-c-so-on-osx)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you to set Anaconda up. Then follow below steps;

- Create a new environment in anaconda.
- Install Jupyter Notebook and launch it. If it works, turn it off.
- Change your anaconda environment in your terminal.
- Try installation commands below;
  conda install ...
  conda install forge ...
  pip install ...