# Issue migrating on m1 mac: geos incompatible architecture

Tags: django, apple-m1, migrate, geos

I have run through a setup and I'm having issues migrating my app (within my venv). When I run `python manage.py migrate` I recevie this error:

```
      OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib, 0x0006): 
    tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib//libgeos_c.dylib' (mach-o file, but is
     an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),
 '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib//libgeos_c.1.16.0.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.10.2/lib/libgeos_c.1.16.0.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

I've tried the answers to this question ([missing libgeos_c.so on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294556/missing-libgeos-c-so-on-osx)), but none of them are working for me. I've also tried adding `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/` to my ~/.bash_profile.

The output of `file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.10.2/lib/libgeos.dylib` =

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.10.2/lib/libgeos.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

The output of `file $(which python3)` =

```
/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is the Django version you are using?

Comment: django version = 1.11.29

Comment: As far as I am aware Django 1.11 does not suport new geos versions for which there is m1 compatibility. I have got no time to chech source but Django 1.11 is EOL and will not recieve updates anyway

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I was having was due to the fact that I had mulitple python versions/architectures installed on the venv and the venv was selecting different pythons. My solution was to delete the venv and create a new one with just python 3.8